# iis8 rewrite web config for https multiple applications

Tags: web-config, url-rewriting, redirect, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

Been struggling with this and can't get it to work. Can't find any answers online.

I have tried the web.config in the root (www.example.com) and in the application (www.example.com/APP_SSL)

Basically, I have an iis 8 server with multiple websites.

For one particular website. (say example.com) I want suborders to always redirect to https.  Specifically these sub folders are Applications.

I am also trying to redirect example.com -> www.example.com at the same time.

Here is what I want to accomplish:  (sorry if I am too verbose)

```
example.com/APP_SSL/... -> httpS://www.example.com/APP_SSL/...
www.example.com/APP_SSL/... -> httpS://www.example.com/APP_SSL/...
```

BUT for other files and applications just be sure we have the www part.
I can live without this stuff as long as the above works.

```
example.com ->  http://www.example.com  
www.example.com -> http://www.example.com  (yes I know this is always true)
example.com/file.htm  -> http:/www.example.com/file.htm
www.example.com/file.htm  -> http:/www.example.com/file.htm

example.com/APP/ -> http://www.example.com/APP/...
www.example.com/APP/ -> http://www.example.com/APP/...
```

I have tried this, but it really does not do anything that I want.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com/APP_SSL$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://www.example.com/APP_SSL/{R:1}" />
</rule>
</rules>
<rewriteMaps>
<rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
<add key="on" value="https" />
<add key="off" value="http" />
</rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Putting this in my /APP_SSL/Web.Config gets me most of what I want with the exception of the example.com -> www.example.com

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/APP_SSL/{R:0}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
</rules>
<rewriteMaps>
<rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
<add key="on" value="https" />
<add key="off" value="http" />
</rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```